# ICarousel View not Updated

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, icarousel

Hello I have Used I carousel in my App to display tweets. Although the process took a lot of time for the viewcontroller to be displayed , so i have used GDC to be able to load the view controller , then the Carousel view to be updated when it downloads the tweets

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (!view)
    {
        //load new item view instance from nib
        //control events are bound to view controller in nib file
        view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Empty" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

        //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadthetweets) withObject:nil ];
        //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadfromtheweb:) withObject:nil];
        //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadthetweets) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];


        //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadthetweets) withObject:nil];
        /*
        NSString *feedname=@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=shoplog1&count=20";

        NSURL *feedURL =[NSURL URLWithString:feedname];

        //The JSON Part
        NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];

        NSError* error;
        _tweets= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                   error:&error];



        maintext=[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"text"];
        NSArray *piecesOfOriginalString = [maintext componentsSeparatedByString:@"http"];
        NSString *firstetxt=[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"The first text: %@",firstetxt);
        NSString *link=[@"http" stringByAppendingString:[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:1]];
        linktogo=[NSURL URLWithString:link];
        text.text=firstetxt;

        NSLog(@"The link text: %@",link);
        //NSDictionary *new =[[[tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"entities"]objectForKey:@"urls"];
        NSDictionary *retweeted=[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"];
        if (retweeted) {
            NSString *urlll=[[[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"]objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
            NSURL *iiii=[NSURL URLWithString:urlll];
            usericon.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:iiii]];
            username.text=[[[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"]objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
        }else{
            username.text=@"Shoplog";
            usericon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyIcon copy_57.png"];
        }
         */
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        [Provideractivity startAnimating];
        [ContentActivity startAnimating];

        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

            [self loadthetweets];
            //[self loadfromtheweb:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:index ]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[self loadfromtheweb:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:index ]];
                maintext=[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"text"];
                NSArray *piecesOfOriginalString = [maintext componentsSeparatedByString:@"http"];
                NSString *firstetxt=[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0];
                NSLog(@"The first text: %@",firstetxt);
                NSString *link=[@"http" stringByAppendingString:[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:1]];
                linktogo=[NSURL URLWithString:link];
                text.text=firstetxt;

                NSLog(@"The link text: %@",link);
                //NSDictionary *new =[[[tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"entities"]objectForKey:@"urls"];
                NSDictionary *retweeted=[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"];
                if (retweeted) {
                    NSString *urlll=[[[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"]objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
                    username.text=[[[[_tweets objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"]objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
                    NSURL *iiii=[NSURL URLWithString:urlll];
                    usericon.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:iiii]];

                }else{
                    username.text=@"Shoplog";
                    usericon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyIcon copy_57.png"];
                }

                [ContentActivity stopAnimating];
                [ContentActivity hidesWhenStopped];
                [Provideractivity stopAnimating];
                [Provideractivity hidesWhenStopped];



                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
            });
        });



    }
    return view;

}
```

What is going wrong here is that 11th element of the Carousel is updated correctly , the rest is blank and I have no idea why.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `if (!view) {...}` block, only create the view, do not configure it. Configure the view after and outside this if statement. The view that is passed into `- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view` could already be created, and if it is it wouldn't get into your if block, and the tweet will never get loaded because if would never be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Answer ! , Although i have managed to put the download of the tweets in a function outside the  `(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view` 
& call it from the initfromnib Function of the view controller
it takes less time right now !